Encapsulated linear memory of Turing Machine
A function $f$ is said to be thinking in an encapsulated linear  memory if:

$f(x)$ is a polynomial block (that is, there exists a polynomial $q$ so that $|f(x)|\leq q(|x|)$) for each input $x$.

There exists a constant $c>0$ and a deterministic $\text{TM}$ (Turing Machine), $M_f$ which, for a given input $(x, i, 0)$, $M_f$ uses-
$c\cdot|x|$ memory cells and returns $f(x)[i]$ values. In addition, for a given input $(x, i, 1)$, $M_f$ uses $c\cdot|x|$ memory cells and returns $1$ if $|f(x)|\leq i$ and returns $0$ otherwise. As above, $x\in \{0,1\}^*$ and $i\in \mathbb{N}$ is an index.


Let $L$ be a language for which there exists a function $f$ thinking in an encapsulated linear memory so that for every $x\in \{0,1\}^*$ there exists: $$f(x)\in \text{3SAT}\longleftrightarrow x\in L.$$
I am interested in this problem: do there exist a polynomial $p(\cdot)$ and a $M_L$ such that the following holds
$$
\exists u\in \{0,1\}^{p(|x|)}M_L(x,u)=1\longleftrightarrow x\in L
$$
and $M_L$ on input $(x, u)$ works in linear memory on $|x|?$

Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4977554/14578.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.
